# Why did pandas give "0.66-0.36" when I tried to add two columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do a simple summation with column name `Tangible Book Value` and `Earnings Per Share`:

```
df['price_asset_EPS'] = (df["Tangible Book Value"]) + (df["Earnings Per Share"])
```

However, the result doesn't evaluate the numbers and also the plus is missing as below

```
0.66-0.36 
1.440.0
```

What I have missed in between?

Comment: It's difficult to tell without a sample of your data - could you `print(df.head())` and edit the result into your post?

Comment: Because both those columns are string not float, probably because `pandas.read_csv` read them in as string; search for how to pass read_csv the right dtype. Show us `print(df.head())` please, in your post.

Answer (score 2):

**Looks like both columns are strings (not float):**

```
0.66-0.36 
1.440.0
```

see how **'+' on those columns did string concatenation instead of addition**? It concatenated "0.66" and "-0.36", then "1.44" and "0.0".

As to **why** those columns are strings not float, look at the dtype that `pandas.read_csv` gave them. There are many duplicate questions here telling you how to specify the right dtypes to read_csv.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your reply. The data is in string, rather than int, hence the plus concatenate the values

Answer (score 0):

Your columns are not being treated as numbers but strings. Try running `df.dtypes`. Against each column, you'll have its type. If you don't see a `float` or `int`, that means these columns have probably been read in as strings.

```
import pandas as pd
dff = pd.DataFrame([[1,'a'], [2, 'b']])
dff.dtypes
0     int64
1    object
```

Below I have created a dataframe with numbers inside quotes. Take a look at the `dtypes`.

```
dff = pd.DataFrame([['1','a'], ['2', 'b']])
dff.dtypes
0    object
1    object
```

Here you can see that numbers column is not marked `int`/`float` because of the quotes. Now, if I take the sum of the first column

```
dff.iloc[:,0].sum()
'12'
```

I get `'12'`, which is the same case as yours. To convert these columns to numeric, look into [pd.to_numeric](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html)

```
dff.iloc[:,0] = pd.to_numeric(dff.iloc[:,0], errors='ignore')
dff.iloc[:,0].sum()
3
```